# One DVR device to standardize video surveillance on multiple sites

Tags: video, video-camera, video-capture

I am looking for a DVR like product capable of following:

- can connect to various CCTV cameras (with a standard BNC output) 
  mostly PAL CVBS.
- downloading of historical data can be performed remotely (nightly) over a secured channel (SFTP, SSH, Windows share etc.), eventually less secure FTP etc. from a distant location over IP network, the format should be preferably chunks of some standard video format like mp4 with H.264 codec
- supports options to embed real-time video output into a custom web page or windows app
- supports good motion detection and good quality with options (ideally storing both motion detected scenes and the whole time separately)
- it would be nice to have a good metadata about videos created, so that output recordings time vs. motion detection could be created programatically
- can be setup to delete old recordings automatically or programatically
- provides option to connect external monitor to show real-time cameras' pictures on site

I am considering creating an intranet video surveillance server. So I am looking for a DVR with good automation options. Ideally with video surveillance server software option.

---

Ok, I just need a good universal and not too expensive device even without points 2 - 3 (downloading ..., embedded video output), if there are any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this one could be good (without 2-3) http://www.dahuasecurity.com/products/hcvr720472087216a-s3-1434.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some considerations I have decided for HIKVISION platform. I chose that platform over DASHUA mostly because of better support in my country and better firmware upgrade program.

Multiple platform (like DASHUA, HIKVISION, AVTECH etc.) cannot be mixed nowadays mostly because ONVIF G standard is not yet widely implemented. Some attempts like Ozeki SDK exist to unify surveillance devices in terms of universal software library, but downloading historical data is not supported on the DVR/NVR devices yet.

So it is better option to buy a new hybrid DVR on every site and use one common software like iVMS 4200.

Such a device is either

[HCVR5104/5108/5116HS-S3](http://www.dahuasecurity.com/products/hcvr510451085116hs-s3-1425.html) with SmartPSS
or

[DS-7204/7208/16HQHI-F1/N](http://www.hikvision.com/en/Products_accessries_364_i5791.html)
with iVMS 4200 (which I chose).

Hope one day the ONVIF G gets implemented and there will be a decent SDK or unversal tools to use it with various devices.